# Is there a better way of waiting for an image to upload to my database then using async and await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

Sorry for the terrible title, I just couldn't figure out a better way of wording it without making it too long.

Anyways, I have a firebase storage where users can upload their profile pictures to. This works well for small sized images that are in the kb, but when uploading images that are bigger (images that are mb big) it takes a while to upload and it messes up the flow of the program. I solved this by simply turning the method into a async function and using await on the blockof code that uploads the image. Here's that block of code

```
 //Uploads the file to the firebase 
  async function onSubmit (file) {
    
//The ref() parameter is what we are setting the path of the users profile picture in our firebase bucket
    await firebase.storage().ref('users/'+user.uid + '/profile.jpg').put(file.target.files[0]).then( () => {
      console.log("Successfully uploaded image")
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error uploading image: " + error);
    });

    downloadProfilePic();
  }
```

It seems to work well enough so far with images as big as 15mb, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this. I'm also not knowledgeable on react and javascript so I might be doing something bad without realizing it also.
Any advice or tips are welcome

Comment: i am not familiar with firebase but on i think it is better to make it asynchrounous since you request to put it on database. And also u can use try catch instead of chaning your methods.

Comment: What do you mean that it would be better to make it asynchronous? Isn't it already? Because of the async keyword in the beginning of the function?

Comment: I don't think there is much more you can do other then show a status and/or progress bar? Also, I assume you're downloading the picture right after to verify it worked? If you trust the firebase service you could potentially skip that step and use the local picture/file.